# Haskell implicit conversions

Tags: haskell, type-conversion

Hello  i was looking to  using `Data.Text.intercalate` and from `Hackage` i do not understand why if the method has the following signature:

`intercalate :: Text -> [Text] -> Text`
 **Why** then, does this work

```
T.intercalate "NI!" ["We", "seek", "the", "Holy", "Grail"]
"WeNI!seekNI!theNI!HolyNI!Grail"
```

Shouldn't you apply `Data.Text.pack` it before each element of the list? 

 Source : http://hackage.haskell.org/package/text-1.2.3.1/docs/Data-Text.html
 
In my case i want to pack the following :

**Input** :`"{"` ,`mytext` ,`"}"` `#mytext::Text` 
 I am doing it with :
`Prelude.intercalate (Data.Text.pack ",") [pack "{",mytext, pack "}"]` or
 
`(pack "{") ++ mytext++ pack "}")` 

 Can someone please explain me why does `Data.Text` expose the same methods as `Data.List` (in our case `intercalate`) and how does it make implicit conversions between `Char` and `Text` ?

Comment: Since you (likely) used `-XOverloadedStrings`, the string literals are *not* `String`s, but `Text`s.

Comment: `Data.Text` exposes the same functions as `Data.List` so that the interface for `Text` values is as close to the interface for `String` (aka `[Char]`) values as possible

Comment: The example is from Hackage not from me .I was just reading the module description on the site.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You likely enabled `-XOverloadedStrings` (or enabled it with the `{-# LANGUAGE OverloadedStrings #-}` at the top of the file).

As a result this means that string *literals* (not string variables, only the literals), can be interpreted by any [**`IsString`**](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.12.0.0/docs/Data-String.html#t:IsString) type.

`Text` is an `IsString` type. So that means that implicitly you use `pack` around the string *literals* (again literals, not ordinary variables).

A similar thing happens with number literals: a number literal can be any `Num` type. Based on what functions you call on the number literal, Haskell can derive the exact type, and thus "interprets" the literal accordingly. For example if you write `atan2 1 2`, then `1` and `2` should be interpreted as `RealFloat` types, whereas for `quot 1 2`, the `1` and `2` are interpreted as Ìntegral` types.

Comment: Thank you for your fast reply but i have not used any `{# #}` whatever that is.(still a beginner).That example is from `Hackage` not from me.

Comment: @BercoviciAdrian: but they demonstrate it with that extension. You can check for yourself: if you import the module in `ghci`, but *without `-XOverloadedStrings`, the above will *not* work. Whereas with the extension it works.