# Haskell: treat newtype as String

Tags: haskell

I often have this simple pattern:

```
newtype Username = Username Text
```

The purpose is of course to increase security when manipulating "Username" and not mix it with other fields.
However, packing and unpacking it all the time becomes tedious.
I wonder if there is a trick to see "Username" as a String (such as AsString or OverloadedStrings), or does it defeats the purpose?

Comment: For what purposes do you find yourself frequently packing & unpacking? Typically with types like this you should only pack when validating or deserialising an arbitrary `Text` string into a username, and likewise only unpack when you need to render or serialise a `Username` back to text or e.g. JSON for display or external communication. All other operations should be able to treat it as an opaque value, and manipulate it only with a few instances of standard typeclasses, or functions you’ve defined (in e.g. a `Username` module if you want to *guarantee* encapsulation, not just encourage it).

Answer (score -1, accepted):

If you want proper type safety, you should use `newtype`. This is designed to prevent you from implicitly converting back and forth to prevent accidental mistakes.

If you simply want a type alias that doesn't get in your way, you should use the type keyword:

```hs
type Username = Text
```

This means a function that takes a `Username` can take `Text` without needing to call a value constructor, etc. In fact, `String` is defined as `type String = [Char]` so you can supply a `[Char]` wherever you need a string; they're equivalent. (Coincidentally, the inefficiency of using linked lists for strings rather than vectors is why `Text` and `ByteString` exist.)

You will still need conversions to make it a `String`, but with this approach there is no distinction between the `Username` and `Text` types other than the semantic hint for people reading your code.

If you want conversions to and from `String`, I'm not too familiar with those language extensions but they look like they'll do the trick, as long as you also use a `type` alias rather than a `newtype` definition.

Comment: Update: according to this [related question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52743607/haskell-implicit-conversions), `{-# LANGUAGE OverloadedStrings #-}` the `OverloadedStrings` extension only converts string *literals* like `"hello"` rather than variables, in the same way number literals are polymorphic. I don't think Haskell supports implicit conversions between different types.

Answer (score 2):

I think your `newtype` approach is a good one. You have to ask yourself why you keep needing to pack and unpack. For a type like this, you should typically have a module defining it, a bunch of tedious typeclass instances, and a few manipulation functions. You just bang it out.

```hs
{-# language GeneralizedNewtypeDeriving #-}

module MyNamespace.Username (.....) where
import Data.Hashable

newtype Username = Username Text
  deriving (Eq, Ord, Show, Hashable)

unUsername :: Username -> Text
validateForm :: Text -> Maybe Username
```

Answer (score 0):

I think it defeats the purpose. Ideally you should only be packing it in input sites (e.g. in your web api, usually implicitly with something like `FromJSON` or `FromHTTPApiData`) and unpacking it only right before usage (e.g. when querying another web api, implicitly via the `ToJSON`, or when querying a db, hopefully again implicitly with some mechanism that allows you to store `Username`s "directly" in your db - for example `EntityField` for persistent)